# Azure blob storage effectiveness

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating an application that is going to be involving a lot of pictures.

I am currently using Windows Azure Blob Storage. I know you're not supposed to store pictures on the database because it takes so much space, instead just store the address and put the files on the disk somewhere on the server.

So I'm wondering if I'm heading into the right direction using Azure Blob? How the speed will be? Would it be costly? How hard would it be to migrate later on so I can store the files on a disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is precisely one of the main usage scenarios for the Azure blobs. There may be scenarios where something else is better, but for most cases that is what you are looking for.

Note depending in the usage it will have, you may enable the cdn service to make it perform best for users around the globe (if each image will be viewed lots of times).

If you end up deciding to move the files later out of the blob storage you can use a tool as cloud berry, or just make a few lines of code. The main thing as usual, would be about the code you put in the application for it; if it is well structured it should be fast to migrate as well.