# system architecture for real-time data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, architecture, bigdata

The company I work for is running a C# project that crawling data from around 100 websites, saving it to the DB and running some procedures and calculations on that data.

Each one of those 100 websites is having around 10,000 events, and each event is saved to the DB.

After that, the data that was saved is being generated and aggregated to 1 big xml file, so each one of those 10,000 events that were saved, is now presented as a XML file in the DB.

This design looks like that:

```
1) crawling 100 websites to collects the data and save it the DB.
2) collect the data that was saved to the DB and generate XML files for each event
3) XML files are saved to the DB
```

The main issue for this post, is the selection of the saved XML files.

Each XML is about 1MB, and considering the fact that there are around 10,000 events, I am not sure SQL Server 2008 R2 is the right option.

I tried to use Redis, and the save is working very well (and fast!), but the query to get those XMLs works very slow (even locally, so network traffic wont be an issue).

I was wondering what are your thoughts? please take into consideration that it is a real-time system, so caching is not an option here.

Any idea will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than store the large XML files in the database, would it not save resources if you were to save the event data in an event table and produce the XML file for the event/s when the data is queried? This would also allow you to produce multiple types of formats for the events such as HTML, JSON etc. It would also allow you run queries on the events should you need to at any point - such as events happening in the next 2 days etc.

Comment: Those XML are being queried hundreds of times every minute, so it will take long time to generate them in run-time, almost impossible. I prefer to generate them once, save them in the DB, and provide all our clients with those XMLs. The issue is, maybe SQL Server 2k8 R2 is not the right option.

Comment: So are these fixed XML files and a client query will produce one or more based on some kind of criteria?

Comment: @IdoLazar I think you misunderstood me. If you're querying the database for the XML data hundreds of times per second, its going to be much quicker to return the primitive data rather than huge chunks of XML. Generate XML once and cache, or memcache, the files. Do a test, benchmark it. I could be wrong. Alternatively, you could try using a different data format such as JSON, which is much less "bulky" than XML. It may increase performance a little. Personally if possible I'd re-plan and redesign the system. Of course, that's not possible in many cases.

Comment: I am also agree with James...@ldoLazar..give it a shot and see I hope if those XML are being queried hundreds of times every minute better cache those at server application !!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DB you could try a cloud-base system (Azure blobs or Amazon S3), it seems to be a perfect solution. See this post: [azure blob storage effectiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176799/azure-blob-storage-effectiveness), same situation, except you have XML files instead of images. You can use a DB for storing the metadata, i.e. source and event type of the XML, the path in the cloud, but not the data itself.

You may also zip the files. I don't know the exact method, but it can surely be handled on client-side. Static data is often sent in zipped format to the client by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some details such as how long does your data need to remain in the database and such…

I’d avoid storing XML in database if you already have the raw data. Why not have an application that will query the database and generate XML reports on demand? This will save you a lot of space.

10GBs  of data  per day is something SQL Server 2008 R2 can handle with the right hardware and good structure optimization. You’ll need to investigate if standard edition will be enough or you’ll have to use enterprise or data center licenses.

In any case answer is yes – SQL Server is capable of handling this amount of data but I’d check other solutions as well to see if it’s possible to reduce the costs in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic arch doesn't seem to be at fault, its the way you've perceived the redis, basically if you design your key=>value right there is no way that the retrieval from redis could be slow.

for ex- lets say I have to store 1 mil objects in redis, and say there is an id against which I am storing my objects, this key is nothing but a guid, the save will be really quick, but when it comes to retrieval, do I know the "key" if i KNOW the key it'll be fast, but if I don't know it or I am trying to retrieve my data not on the basis of key but on the basis of some Value in my objects, then off course it'll be slow.
The point is - when it comes to retrieval you should just work against the "Key" and nothing else, so design your key like a pre-calculated value in itself; so when I need to get some data from redis/memcahce, I could **make the KEY**, and just do a single hit to get the data.

If you could put more details, we'll be able to help you better.